Pyomo + IPOPT Max Iterations reached without optimality
I have been working on an optimal control problem using Pyomo + IPOPT, but I just cannot find an optimal solution. It is a 3 phase trajectory problem with an objective of minimizing mass flow rate(minimizing fuel consumption). I have formulated the objective by specifying the that the final total mass of the third phase is maximized:
Objective(expr=m.mass_3[1], sense=maximize)
I have made sure that the problem is formulated correctly, and also made sure it is scaled properly. Any suggestions?
P.S. I have also used a max iterations of 2000, but to no avail.
I would be grateful for any kind of help.
[enter image description here](https://i.sstatic.net/x4hT1SiI.png)

Does this answer your question? Pyomo: Ipopt maximum numbers of iterations exceeded

Maybe your problem is just too complex to be solved in 2000 iterations. Try increasing the number of iterations and see what happens

Thanks for you answer, but unfortunately I have tried 10,000 iterations and still did not work

If you have ensured that the problem is correctly formulated, the iterations should not take that long. The issue is primarily due to numerical instability. When using quaternions, it is important to maintain normality in numerical analysis. To achieve this, a factor of {k * error * q} should be added to the right side.
The error can be calculated as:
error=1−(q0^2+q1^2+q2^2+q3^2)
where q is a four-element quaternion vector.
According to the book:
https://arc.aiaa.org/doi/book/10.2514/4.102509
kΔt<=1. You have to play around with the k values to find what works for you.
Here is a snippet of one element of quaternion of what I did:
k = 0.0000000000005
error = 1 - ((q0^2) + (q1^2) + (q2^2) + (q3^2))
(q0dot) = ((0.5 * ((0 * q0) - (p * q1) - (q * q2) - (r * q3))) + (k * error * q0))
Hope this helps anyone struggling with the same problem
